# "Access is denied due to invalid credentials" REST API error. How to solve?

Tags: rest, ibm-watson, watson, personality-insights

I followed the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/personality-insights/api/v3/?java#introduction): and [here](https://console.bluemix.net/services/personality_insights/b6ccc311-635d-4f19-ae1d-7f6ba9312b29?paneId=gettingStarted&ace_config=%7B%22region%22%3A%22us-south%22%2C%22orgGuid%22%3A%2285617358-5a0a-42fb-b56a-d16510af1711%22%2C%22spaceGuid%22%3A%22e3a155ea-4a64-41ea-adff-d79c494d9888%22%2C%22redirect%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.bluemix.net%2Fdashboard%2Fapps%22%2C%22bluemixUIVersion%22%3A%22v6%22%7D&env_id=ibm%3Ayp%3Aus-south): Trying to integrate to a Personality Insights service via Android Java. 
However, after the app runs, and using the correct username and password as mentioned in the guide... (the guide is not clear (2nd bullet point in "Before you begin") on which set of credentials to use - It says get the "service credentials" and credentials from the new service created - I tried with both and both fail with the same error below.)

**Error:**

12-11 01:49:56.201 29584-29632/? I/CredentialUtils: JNDI string lookups is not available. 12-11 01:49:56.269 29584-29632/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default 12-11 01:49:56.723 29584-29632/? D/OkHttp: --> POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2017-10-13 http/1.1 (1297-byte body) 12-11 01:49:56.803 29584-29632/? D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Not Authorized https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2017-10-13 (78ms, unknown-length body) 12-11 01:49:56.863 29584-29632/? E/WatsonService: POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2017-10-13, status: 401, error: Not Authorized 12-11 01:49:56.865 29584-29632/? E/ERROR: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.processServiceCall(WatsonService.java:492) at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$2.execute(WatsonService.java:254) at com.upen.personalityapp.MainActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:105) at com.upen.personalityapp.MainActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:87) at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:306) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:244) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 12-11 01:49:56.866 29584-29584/?

This is the code I am using; I am trying to pass a "text" input to the service.

```
        service = new PersonalityInsights("2017-10-13");
        service.setUsernameAndPassword("{myUsername}", "{myPassword}");
        Profile profile = service.getProfile(text).execute();
        System.out.println(profile);
        return profile.toString();
```

I am using the `com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:personality-insights:3.8.0` dependency.

I tried connecting to the URL in the error (https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2017-10-13 ) via a browser. It prompts for a username/password combo. I entered my details from my IBM Cloud Lite service but it throws the HTTP Error 405. Is this how it's supposed to work on the browser?

Comment: You need to pass the credentials as `service.setUsernameAndPassword(username, password);`

Comment: Yes I am passing my credentials there. I used 'myUsername' and 'myPassword' so as to not expose it here. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe i was not clear in my comment. Use (myUsername, myPassword) instead of ("{myUsername}", "{myPassword}");

Comment: Instead of service.setUsernameAndPassword(username, password);, I tried service.setUsernameAndPassword("username", "password"); and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: By any chance, do you also know how to process the returned JSON output and display it as a pie chart? Just looking for an overview of how to best achieve that. Here's a sample output: https://justpaste.it/1ei1o

Comment: That is a different question for a different thread. Raise a new question for it.

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone in the future;

Instead of `service.setUsernameAndPassword(username, password);`, I tried `service.setUsernameAndPassword("username", "password");` and it worked.